# Excel VBA split data in a cell and copy it to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to VBA and I'm stuck with a problem that probably has an easy solution.

In Cell A1 I have a string "UP 5487441 - some more text". I'd need to get only "OUP5487441" (yes without the space and text) to another worksheet into cell C3.

I have digged around a lot to find a solution for this but I only keep finding functions but I need it to be a part of a bigger VBA macro that's to be used for several files. But the data is always in cell A1.

If anyone has any tips I'm very thankful!

Greets

Sanved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Dim splitValues() as String

splitValues = Split(ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).Value)

Sheet2.Cells(3,3).Value = splitValues(0) & splitValues(1)
```

Obviously, you can make this considerably more robust when you add it to your existing code, but this is the general strategy to use.

Comment: Thanks very much! Works like a charm!